# Have write-host output to a file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Okay so I'm working in Powershell and am trying to have "write-host" output to a file. Here is the code I'm working with right now

```
Function CreateNugetPackage {
    Param(
        [String] $File
    )
    Process {
        $retCode = 0
        write-verbose "Getting version of $file..."
        $version = (Get-Item $File).VersionInfo.FileVersion
        $id = $file.Substring(0, $File.LastIndexof('.'))
        $filepath = Get-ChildItem "$File"
        $OriginalFilename = (Get-Item $File).VersionInfo.OriginalFilename
        write-verbose "$id"
        write-verbose "$filepath"
        $id > test.txt
        write-host $filepath >> test.txt
```

So the $id generates the name of the file without the extension and what I'm trying to do with the $filepath is have it output the host to the test.txt file. I've tried doing "write-output $filepath >> test.txt" but that didn't work the way I wanted it to. Instead of outputing the host it outputted

```
Directory: C:\Users\mhopper\Documents\CreateNugetPackage


    Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
    ----                -------------     ------ ----                              
    -ar--        10/22/2014   9:17 AM    5534208 AjaxControlToolkit.dll
```

instead of just "C:\Users\mhopper\Documents\CreateNugetPackage\AjaxControlToolkit.dll"

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Try `$filepath.FullName` as well. `Get-ChildItem` returns `FileInfo` (or `DirectoryInfo`) objects which PowerShell formats in a special way.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That worked exactly like I wanted it to, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect output from `Write-Host` (it doesn't populate the output stream and cannot be piped).

Comment: I tried doing write-output instead of write host and it generates 

Directory: C:\Users\mhopper\Documents\CreateNugetPackage


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
-ar--        10/22/2014   9:17 AM    5534208 AjaxControlToolkit.dll

instead of "C:\Users\mhopper\Documents\CreateNugetPackage\AjaxControlToolkit.dll"

Comment: @Macauley Look at Mike Z's comment on your post. You need to use `$filepath.FullName`